# How to emulate C enumeration in XSLT with optional values

Tags: c, xslt

I'm trying to make a XSLT conversion that generates C code, the following XML should be converted:

```
<enum name="anenum">
  <enumValue name="a"/>
  <enumValue name="b"/>
  <enumValue name="c" data="10"/>
  <enumValue name="d" />
  <enumValue name="e" />
</enum>
```

It should convert to some C code as following:

```
enum anenum {
   a = 0,
   b = 1,
   c = 10,
   d = 11,
   e = 12
}
```

or alternatively (as the C preprocessor will handle the summation):

```
   enum anenum {
       a = 0,
       b = 1,
       c = 10,
       d = c+1,
       e = c+2
    }
```

The core of my XSLT looks like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="enumValue">
  <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
  <xsl:text> = </xsl:text>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length(@data)&gt;0">
      <xsl:value-of select="@data"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="position()-1"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  <xsl:text>,
```

(for simplicity I skip some of the 'no comma at the last element' code)

This example will not generate the correct values for **d** and **e**

I've been trying to get it working for the variable **d** and **e**, but so far I'm unsuccessful.

Using constructions like:

```
<xsl:when test="string-length(preceding-sibling::enumValue[1]/@datavalue)&gt;0">
    <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::enumValue/@data + 1"/>
</xsl:when>
```

...only work for the first one after the specified value (in this case **d**).

Who can help me? I'm probably thinking too much in a procedural way...

Comment: I have improved the solution that uses keys and now it seems really good, see my new answer. :)

Comment: @Roalt But if something is marked "community wiki" this prevents it for receiving further votes -- not a good thing.

Comment: @Roalt But the last answer is also implemented. And it works. Or what do you mean by "but I use your previous answer because (1) it's implemented and it works "

Comment: @Roalt I am glad even the first answer works for yo :) I would still recommend using the second one as more robust, efficient and ellegant.

Comment: @Roalt you may send email to the SO administration: team@stackoverflow.com and ask them to undo the community-wiki operation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A nonrecursive solution, using keys**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="koffsetEnums" match="enumValue[@data]"
  use="generate-id()"/>

    <xsl:template match="enum">
      enum <xsl:value-of select="@name"/> {
      <xsl:apply-templates select="enumValue"/>
      }
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="enumValue">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name, ' = ')"/>

      <xsl:variable name="voffsetValueId" select=
       "generate-id((. | preceding-sibling::enumValue)
                                            [@data][last()]
                  )"/>

      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not($voffsetValueId)">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(),'&#xA;      ')"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:variable name="vinitOffset" select=
           "key('koffsetEnums', $voffsetValueId)/@data"
           />

           <xsl:value-of select=
            "$vinitOffset
            +
               count(preceding-sibling::enumValue)
             -
               count(key('koffsetEnums', $voffsetValueId)/preceding-sibling::enumValue)
            "
            />
           <xsl:text>&#xA;      </xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above transformation is applied on the originally provided XML document**:

```
<enum name="anenum">
    <enumValue name="a"/>
    <enumValue name="b"/>
    <enumValue name="c" data="10"/>
    <enumValue name="d" />
    <enumValue name="e" />
</enum>
```

**the required result is produced**:

```
enum anenum {
      a = 1
      b = 2
      c = 10
      d = 11
      e = 12

      }
```

Comment: Wow, this one is also nice! I've also considered keys but did not quite know how to manage them!

Comment: @Roalt I have improved the solution and now it seems really good, see my new answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

**A better solution with keys, avoiding most use of the preceding-sibling axis**:

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
<!--                                              -->   
    <xsl:key name="ksimpleEnValues" match="enumValue[not(@data)]"
     use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::enumValue[@data][1])"/>
<!--                                              -->       
    <xsl:template match="enum">
    enum <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
         {      
          <xsl:apply-templates select=
           "key('ksimpleEnValues', '')
           "/>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="enumValue[@data]"/>
         }
    </xsl:template>
<!--                                              -->
    <xsl:template match="enumValue">
      <xsl:param name="pOffset" select="0"/>
        <xsl:value-of select=
         "concat(@name, ' = ', position()+$pOffset,'&#xA;      ')"/>
    </xsl:template>
<!--                                              -->
    <xsl:template match="enumValue[@data]">
        <xsl:value-of select=
         "concat(@name, ' = ', @data,'&#xA;      ')"/>
<!--                                              -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select=
           "key('ksimpleEnValues', generate-id())">
       <xsl:with-param name="pOffset" select="@data"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>       
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the originally-provided XML document**:

```
<enum name="anenum">
    <enumValue name="a"/>
    <enumValue name="b"/>
    <enumValue name="c" data="10"/>
    <enumValue name="d" />
    <enumValue name="e" />
</enum>
```

**Produces the wanted result**:

```
enum anenum
 {      
  a = 1
  b = 2
  c = 10
  d = 11
  e = 12
 }
```

**Explanation**:

1. The key named `ksimpleEnValues` indexes all `enumValue` elements that do not have the `data` attribute. The indexing is done by the generate-id() value of the first preceding `enumValue` element that has a `data` attribute.
2. Thus `key('ksimpleEnValues', someId)` is the nodeset containing all `enumValue` elements following the `enumValue` that has its generate-id() equal to `someId`, and all these `enumValue` elements are preceding the next `enumValue` with a `data` attribute, if such exists.
3. key('ksimpleEnValues', '') is the node-set of all `enumValue` elements that do not have a preceding `enumValue` element with a `data` attribute.
4. The template that matches `enumValue` takes an optional parameter `$pOffset`, in which the value of the `data` attribute from the immediate preceding `enumValue` element with this attribute, will be passed, otherwise the default value for `$pOffset` is 0.
5. The template matching `enumValue` elements that have a `data` attribute produces its enum-value (@name = @data) and then applies templates to all `enumValue` elements between itself and the next (if such exists) `enumValue` with a `data` attribute. The value of the `data` attribute is passed as the `$pOffset` parameter and it will be added to the relative position of each selected `enumValue` element when producing the output from its processing.

Comment: If anybody can explain why this answer has become "community wiki", I would greatly appreciate it. ?!?

Comment: I put the flag there when I accepted the first/initial answer.

Comment: I think this improvement is probably better than your previous answer, but I use your previous answer because (1) it's implemented and it works and (2) the performance isn't an issue.

Comment: @Roalt But if something is marked "community wiki" this prevents it for receiving further votes -- not a good thing.

Comment: @Roalt But the last answer is also implemented. And it works.
 Or what do you mean by "but I use your previous answer because (1) it's implemented and it works "

Comment: Ok, thanks for telling me on the community wiki, I won't do it again.

Comment: @Dimitre The accepted answer was put in some other more complex XSLT code with some slightly different tag-names including namespaces. I don't need the extra performance of your improved solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change "variables" in xsl but you can use recursion. Don't use preceding-sibling predicates unless absolutely urgent as they will kill your performance.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:template match="/" >
        <xsl:call-template name="printEnum">
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="0"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="position" select="1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="printEnum">
        <xsl:param name="position"/>    
        <xsl:param name="value" select="0"/>
        <xsl:variable name="node" select="/enum/enumValue[$position]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="enumValue">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$node/@data">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$node/@data"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$value + 1"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>       
        </xsl:variable>     
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($node/@name, ' = ', $enumValue, ' , ')"/>
        <xsl:if test="/enum/enumValue[$position + 1]">
            <xsl:call-template name="printEnum">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$enumValue"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! However, you have to change in the last call-template, the line <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value"/>
into <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$enumValue"/> in order to let it work.